# Choose a method for buffering file contents in C

Tags: c, buffering

We have different ways to buffering a file contents (pass/return buffer to/from function and where/when to allocating memory). All of these functions work for me, but which one is the most standard way or recommended way?

#### 1:

```
void buffering(FILE *file, char **buffer, int size)
{
    *buffer = (char *) malloc (size);
    read( input , *buffer , size );
}
```

call:

```
char *buf;
buffering( file, &buf, size);
```

#### 2:

```
void buffering(FILE *file, char *buffer, int size)
{
    read( input , buffer , size );
}
```

call:

```
char *buf
buf = (char *) malloc (size);
buffering( file, buf, size);
```

### 3:

```
char *buffering(FILE *file, int size)
{
    char *buffer = (char *) malloc (size);
    read( input , buffer , size );
    return buffer;
}
```

call:

```
char *buf = buffering( file, size);
```

#### 4: (tell me)

Comment: What's that `FILE *file` paramter that is not used in your different functions. ANd your functions won't compile. I suppose "file" should be "input".

Comment: None of those work with the standard (POSIX) `read()` function; it takes a file descriptor, not a file pointer. Plus you pass in `FILE *file` and read from (unidentified variable) `input`. If you use `fread()` (and add the extra argument), then any of them could work.  You don't test whether the read succeeded; you have no way to report whether the read succeeded.  You probably need to know whether it did succeed.  (1) or (3) could co-opt the return pointer and set it null if the read fails.

Comment: The `FILE*` function family are already buffered by default, so much so that in many implementations `fgetc()` is is little more than a macro around that buffering implementation. Until such time as you've determine the standard io buffering isn't sufficient (there are some platforms where it definitely *isn't*), I'm not sure what you're hoping to gain.

Comment: Sorry! It's my bad mistake. I must changed `FILE *file` with `int fd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocating a buffer inside a function is considered bad practice. This is because the call to `malloc` (or `new`) is masked by the function call and **the caller doesn't see the buffer allocation** and is not clear to him (unless reviewing the function documentation) that he is responsible to `free` (or `delete`) the buffer.

In general there has to be an "owner" of the buffer. This owner has to be responsible to **both** allocating and freeing the buffer.

So to answer your question

```
void buffering(FILE *file, char *buffer, int size);
```

is the only one good. The others are bad for the reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

The most recommended way is encapsulating all buffering into an opaque structure like it is done with the `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose` family of functions.

Comment: @vonbrand: Why "hand off" ? I don't mean fiddling around with the FILE structue, but rather implement whatever buffering in a similar way as it is done in fopen etc.

Comment: The stdio library already implements sophisticated buffering, written by people who presumably have forgotten more about the system than I'll ever learn. Unless there is an *extremely* strong case to be made otherwise, just use what the language offers and spend your time on something more productive.

Comment: @vonbrand: perfectly true, it doesn't make sense rewriting file buffering when we already have stdio, but I suppose the asker wants to know about buffering in a more general manner.